# How many models does caret::trainControl() actually train?

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I searched around CV and the caret documentation but couldn't find an answer to this. I'm using `caret` in R to tune some random forests for classification trained using `ranger`. I've made a tuning grid that varies the number of variables sampled, `mtry`, and the minimum node size, `min.node.size` in this dataset. I defined the grid as follows:

```
mtry <- floor(sqrt(ncol(train_x)))

grid_rf <- expand.grid(
  .mtry = c(mtry/4, mtry/2, mtry, mtry*2, mtry*4),
  .splitrule = "gini",
  .min.node.size = c(1, 10, 20)
)
```

So this grid should yield 15 models. Next, I set the trainControl function to use out of bag error, `trainControl(method = "oob")`. There are no repeats, because the method isn't repeated cross-validation. So I would only expect 15 models to be trained and the model with lowest OOB error to be chosen. However, looking at the `"Growing trees.. Progress: X%"` progress message that ranger prints, I can see that right now it's starting to train the 16th random forest instead of stopping, because it has already hit 100% 15 times and is starting to train a new forest.

Did I misunderstand the trainControl() function? How many models is it supposed to train?

Thanks for reading my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one additional training, the one that produces `finalModel`, the model trained on "all the training data using the optimal parameter set" (final step in algorithm [displayed here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#basic)).  Now with oob scoring, you don't really need to refit because you already were using all the training data, but it appears that `caret` doesn't make that specialization (I don't see any exceptions for oob scoring around this part of the code, for either [`train.default`](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/8159c8315402e44d50e97eec564b2f25da5dbc0d/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R#L826) or [`train.recipe`](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/8159c8315402e44d50e97eec564b2f25da5dbc0d/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R#L1413)).